# Angular UI Bootstrap DatePicker customClass function not firing inside $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to have my datePicker update when its scope changes.  I have added a watch but this seems to prevent the customClass function from firing.

Directive HTML

```
<datepicker-calendar search-response="searchResponse"></datepicker-calendar>
```

Directive template (datepicker)

```
<div uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options" ng-if="dt"></div>
```

Angular Directive Code

```
var datepickerCalendarDirective = function datepickerCalendarDirective() {
        return {
            scope: {
                searchResponse: '='
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: './templates/directive.datepickerCalendar.tmpl.html',
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs, $filter, policySessionService) {

                scope.$watch('searchResponse', function () {

                    scope.dt = new Date();

                    if (!scope.searchResponse) return '';

                    /* setup the date picker options object.
                     * this takes a customClass function which sets the 
                     * css class of the trips/events on the datepicker
                     */
                    scope.options = {
                        customClass: getSelectedDates,
                        maxDate: new Date(),
                        showWeeks: false,
                        startingDay: 1 };
                }, true);

                /* Iterate over each trip in the reponse and return either
                * a trip or incident css class to the customClass param
                * of the datepicker options object
                */
                function getSelectedDates(data) {
                    if (scope.searchResponse.data[0] && data.mode === 'day') {
                        var trips = $filter('orderBy')(scope.searchResponse.data[0].tripDates, 'JourneyDate'),
                            journeyDate;

                        for (var i = 0; i < trips.length; i++) {
                            journeyDate = new Date(trips[i].JourneyDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                            if (journeyDate === new Date(data.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
                                // return the appropriate css class for the trip type (trip or incident)
                                if (trips[i].IncidentRecorded) {
                                    return 'incident';
                                } else {
                                    return 'trip';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return '';
                }

                // });
            }
        };
    };
```

if i remove the scope watch then everything works as expected and the customClass function fires as not

Comment: Can you please provide `./templates/directive.datepickerCalendar.tmpl.html`. Also why you even need to reinit datepicker, you could watch model, and just only change class on parent element

Comment: I have added the datepicker template as requested

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think problem in

```
 if (journeyDate === new Date(data.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
```

I believe `setHours` modify somehow original date object

So to prevent it you can preserve data object with

```
function getSelectedDates(data) {
     var _data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

And use `_data` instead of `data`

**UPDATE**

I've created a JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/y1mt01w2/), so in console.log `getSelectedDates()` is firing, but what is the point of `if (!$scope.searchResponse) return '';`?

Comment: Umm, the issue i have is that when the watch fires, the customClass function of the options object does not even fire.  This only occurs if i have a watch, otherwise it works just fine?

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed this issue, with the help of @Leguest :)

The issue was in the timing.  it seemed that the model was not ready before the datepicker was rendering.